# Control the font size of axis tick labels

Tags: r, axis, label

Probably a trivial question but nevertheless I couldn't find a straightforward answer for it online.

Suppose I plot this data:

```
plot(c(1:10),rnorm(10),xaxt="n",xlab="")
```

And then I want to plot my own defined x-axis labels:

```
x.labs=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
axis(1,at=c(1:10),labels=x.labs)
```

My question is how do I adjust the font size of the labels (make `x.labs` bigger or smaller)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cex.axis`:

```
plot(c(1:10), rnorm(10), xaxt = "n", xlab = "")    
x.labs = letters[1:10]
axis(1, at = c(1:10), labels = x.labs, cex.axis = 1.5)
```